# What happend when send TCP packet with SYN + FIN flag set or another multi violating flag?

Tags: tcp

What happend when send TCP packet with SYN + FIN flag set or another multi violating flag ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many scanning tools use SYN FIN packets, because many intrusion detection systems did not catch these in the past,but now any system can safely assume that SYN FIN packets are malicious..

`SYN FIN PSH`, `SYN FIN RST`, `SYN FIN RST PSH` , and other variants on `SYN FIN` also exist. These packets may be used by attackers who are aware that intrusion detection systems may be looking for packets with just the SYN and FIN bits set, Again, these are clearly malicious..

Although The method to handle this flag combinations is not conveyed in the RFC of TCP so it's treated differently by OS ( each OS generate his own error response but the violation is always detected )